# ADO stages being skipped despite conditions being met

Tags: azure-devops, cicd, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've spent longer than I care to admit on this, and am now seeking some expert Azure DevOps YAML pipeline support.

We have multiple deployment environments. Sometimes we make Terraform changes which only affect a single environment. I'm using a `git diff` to determine whether or not we need to deploy to these environments.

Each environment has multiple stages - Git Diff, Pre-checks, Deployment, Post-checks

The pipeline chain therefore looks something like this:

[image: pipeline chain]

If the Git Diff stage finds changed files related to the environment, the other stages in that environment (checks and deployment) then proceed. If not, they should be skipped, and move on to the next environment.

The Git Diff stage works fine - I ouput a `changed` variable, and if it's `1`, the Pre-check stage runs as expected.

However... the deployment stage then gets skipped.

I'm using the following conditions on my stages:

- Pre-checks

```yaml
condition: eq(dependencies.GitDiff_Stage_${{ parameters.env }}.outputs['GitDiff_Job.GitDiff_Task.changed'], '1')
```

- Deployment

```yaml
condition: eq(stageDependencies.ClusterChecks_pre_${{ parameters.env }}.ClusterCheck.result, 'Succeeded')
```

If I change the deployment condition to `always()` or `not(or(failed(), canceled()))`, it runs. If I change the condition to `and(always(), eq(stageDepe...` or `and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), eq(stageDepe...`) it does not run.

Naturally here you would figure that the condition isn't working... but if I create a separate stage with condition `always()` and run the following code:

```yaml
stages:
  - stage: test_${{ parameters.env }}
    condition: always()
    dependsOn:
      - ${{ each dependency in parameters.depends_on_stage }}:
          - ${{ dependency }}
    jobs:
      - job: test
        variables:
          test: $[ eq(stageDependencies.ClusterChecks_pre_${{ parameters.env }}.ClusterCheck.result, 'Succeeded') ]
        steps:
          - bash: |
              echo "eq(stageDependencies.ClusterChecks_pre_${{ parameters.env }}.ClusterCheck.result, 'Succeeded')"
              echo $(test)
```

[image: test stage]

... I see `False` where the Pre-checks haven't run, and `True` where they have - yet the deployment stage is still skipped.

[image: show working condition]

So if the condition evaluates to `True`, why on earth is the stage still being skipped?

All of the correct dependencies exist.

My best guess is because previous deployment jobs have been skipped.. but I don't know how to work around this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not an answer, but remember you can see the compiled pipeline in the upper right corner elipses (download) of a build. In this case my first place to go would be to download the compiled pipeline and see what it actually compiled to. Hope this helps.
Often these problem lies in not properly managing the different scopes and compile-time and run-time

Comment: I genuinely didn't know that existed. Hard to read, but might be exactly what I need. Thank you @CasperLeonNielsen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression "**`stageDependencies.<stage-name>.<job-name>.result`**" is for [job to job dependencies across stages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#job-to-job-dependencies-across-stages). It is available for the job-level and not for the stage-level.

If you use this expression at stage-level, it will not be able to fetch the job result from the previous depended stage. Instead, it could get a **`Null`** value.

For your case, at the stage-level, you can change to use the expression "**`dependencies.<stage-name>.result`**" to check the result of the whole previous depended stage.

In addition, when you set the condition '**`always()`**' or '**`not(or(failed(), canceled()))`**' at stage-level, it just checks the status of the previous depended stage, not the status of jobs in the previous stage.

for more details, see "[**Expressions - Dependencies**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies)".

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out. Presumably the reason I could still `echo` the condition is because it was running as part of a Job? Whereas the Stage condition is done "behind the scenes"?

Comment: Can confirm this worked. Sigh!! Thanks for your help and quick response, really appreciate that.